# What is the Difference Between Classes vs Protocols

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, protocols

I'm going through the docs because I am about to implement a protocol instead of a class (something I've never done before), and I'm curious as to the difference between the two.

Can someone give an example in plain words?

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with other OO programming languages, say, Java, C++, or C#? It would be easier to provide an analogy to another language than explain it from scratch.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**A class** serves as a blueprint for creating one or more objects based on specific implementation of that class. 
A good analogy is a form for cutting out butter-cookies. The form‘s attributes (shape, size, height) define the cookies that you can cut out with it. You have only one form (class) but you can create many cookies (instances of that class, ie. objects) with it. All cookies are based on that particular form. 
Similarily all objects that are instances of that class are identical in their attributes.

**Classes =**  **data** and **methods** (special functions), all sophistically bundled together.

Classes define, what their inner **content (data)** is + what kind of **work (methods)** they can do. 
The content is based on variables that hold various number types, strings, constants, and other more sophisiticated content + methods which are chunks of code that (when executed) perform some computational operations with various data.

**All methods** defined in class have their 
**Definition** - that defines the name of the method + what (if any) data the methods takes in for processing and what (if any) data the methods spits out for processing by someone else. All methods defined in class also have **Implementation** – the actual code that  provides the processing – it is the innerworkings of methods.. inside there is code that processes the data and also that is able to ask other methods for subprocessing data. So the class is a very noble type in programming.

If you understand the above, you will understand what a protocol is.

**A protocol** is a set of one or more **method declarations** and that set has a name and represents a protocol. I say declarations, because the methods that together are defined by a particular protocol, **do not have any implementation code defined.**. The only thing that exist is their names declared.
Look above - in class, you have always defined not only what methods the class has, but also how that work will be done. But methods in protocol do not have any implementation.

Lets have a real life analogy again, it helps. If you come to my house to live here for a week, you will need to adhere to my TidyUp protocol. The TidyUp protocol defines three methods - wash the dishes every day, clean the room, and ventilate fresh air. These three methods, I define them..are something you will do. But I absolutely do not care, how the implementation should look like, I just nominaly define the methods. You will implement them, ie.you define how the details of that work (those methods) will look like. I just say, adhere to my protocol and implement it as you see fit.

**Finale** – You can declare some class. You can separately also declare a protocol.  And you can then declare, that  this class, in addition to its own methods, will adopt or adhere to that protocol, ie. the class wil implement the protocol’s methods.

Comment: A protocol is a set of method ***declarations***, not, as you explain, _definitions_.

Answer (score 3):

The plain words from [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1) explain the purpose of protocols simply:

> Protocols declare methods that can be implemented by any class.
>   Protocols are useful in at least three situations:
>
> - To declare methods that others are expected to implement
> - To declare the interface to an object while concealing its class
> - To capture similarities among classes that are not hierarchically related

So, protocols *declare* methods, but don't provide the implementation. A class that adopts a protocol is expected to implement the protocol's methods.

Delegation is a good example of why a protocol is useful. Consider, for example, the UITableViewDataSource protocol. Any class can adopt that protocol, and any class that does so can be used as the data source for a table. A table view doesn't care what kind of object is acting as its data source; it only cares that the object acting as data source implements a particular set of methods. You could use inheritance for this, but then all data source objects would have to be derived from a common base class (more specific than NSObject). Using the protocol instead lets the table count on being able to call methods like `-tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` and `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` without needing to know anything else about the data source.

Answer (score 2):

A protocol is a lot like an interface in Java and other languages. Think of it as a contract that describes the interface other classes agree to implement. It can define a list of required and optional methods that an implementing class will implement. Unlike a class, it does not provide its own implementations of those methods.

Answer (score 2):

the main difference between classes and protocols is that writing protocols is useful to implement delegate methods.

in example we've got class A and class B and we want to call a method in class A from the class B.

you can read a very valuable example of that in this article

http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

reading code is worth a thousand words ;-)

that helped me out the first time I had to use'em

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat less difference than in other languages.  An interface (equivalent to a Java/C++ class) defines the data layout of objects and may define some subset of their methods (including the possibility of defining the entire set, of course).  A protocol defines a subset of methods only, with no data definition.

Of significance is that a interface can inherit from only one other interface (which can, of course, inherit from an interface which inherits from an interface which inherits ...), but an interface can implement any number of protocols.  So two distinct interfaces with no common inheritance (other than NSObject) can both implement the same protocol and thus "certify" that they provide the same functions.  (Though with Objective-C you can, with a few tricks, call methods of an interface that aren't externally declared in either the interface declaration or a protocol, so protocols are to a degree just "syntactic sugar" or some such.)

Answer (score 0):

Protocol defines what a class could do, like a Interface in Java or c#

A class is the actual implementation that does the job.

Simple enough? :)